# facebook javascript sdk call in function

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a function like:

```
export function login(){

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '17214152578458911437894',
        cookie     : true, 
        xfbml      : true, 
        version    : 'v2.1'
    });


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        this.statusChangeCallback(response);
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function fetchUser() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
    });
};

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
        this.fetchUser();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        console.log("Not authorised");
    } else {
        console.log("Please log in to facebook");
    }
};

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    }.bind(this));
};
```

};

and method like:

```
export function handleLogin() {
    var self = login()
    self.FB.login(self.checkLoginState());
    console.log(response) ---> I want the response from facebook 
    };
```

I want to do something like :

```
<button onClick="handleLogin()">Login with facebook</button>
```

When I do this I want to be able to log in to facebook..

I guess my `FB` is not assigned here.. 
It gives me error `Cannot read property 'FB' of undefined.`

How can I call the initialization in my `handleLogin()`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to load and initialize the SDK before you can call any other FB element methods. (You can keep loading and the initialization within your method if you like – but then you need to place all additional calls to FB methods inside the `window.fbAsyncInit` handler.)